# flutter [Instance of 'model'] show data in FutureBuilder error

Tags: flutter

hi i have a question how to show data that i call in provider in future builder ?, im pretty confuse how to implement the method inside of it

menu page code

```
class MenuPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int? id;
  // final menuName;
  // final menuPrice;
  // final menuImg;
  // final menuDetail;

  MenuPage({this.id});

  @override
  State<MenuPage> createState() => _MenuPageState();
}

class _MenuPageState extends State<MenuPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MenuProvider menuProvider = Provider.of<MenuProvider>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: bodyBgColor,
      body: ScrollConfiguration(
        //menambahkan scroll configurasi untuk listview;
        behavior: NoScrollGrow(),
        //widget manual yg berfungsi agar ketika listview mentok di atas / bawah tidak muncul glow berwarna biru;
        child: Center(
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0, bottom: 30.0),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 30.0,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 30.0,
                child: GridView.builder(
                  itemCount: 3,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 15.0,
                    childAspectRatio: 0.8,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
                    return _buildCard(
                        'Cookie Mint',
                        'Rp. 30000',
                        'assets/product_image.png',
                        false,
                        false,
                        context,
                        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.');
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCard(String name, String price, String imgPath, bool added,
      bool isFavorite, context, String desc) {
    var c_height = MediaQuery.of(context)
        .size
        .height; //variabel agar tinggi dynamic full sesuai ukuran layar

    return Padding(
      padding:
          const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, bottom: 5.0, right: 5.0, left: 15.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                spreadRadius: 3.0,
                blurRadius: 5.0)
          ],
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            /*
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/menu-detail',
                arguments: {imgPath: imgPath, name: name, desc: desc});
             */
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => MenuDetail(
                  name: name,
                  imgPath: imgPath,
                  desc: desc,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: c_height * 0.15,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage(imgPath),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  // agar ketika text panjang tidak menampilan error / otomatis menjadi 2 line
                  flex: 0,
                  child: Text(
                    name,
                    style: primaryTextStyle.copyWith(
                        fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: semiBold),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                    flex: 0,
                    child: Text(price,
                        style: primaryTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 12.0))),
                Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        isFavorite
                            ? Icon(Icons.add_circle, color: primaryColor)
                            : Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline,
                                color: primaryColor),
                      ],
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the question is on this code `MenuProvider menuProvider = Provider.of<MenuProvider>(context);`

i want to use that menuProvider to show data based on widget.id that passed before this screen

```
FutureBuilder<List> {
future : menuProvider.menuries,
builder : (context, snapshot) {
if(snapshot.id == widget.id){
return scaffold in my code and show data
}
}
```

but when i print() the result is `[Instance of 'MenuModel']`

this is my MenuModel

```
import 'package:kavarna/pages/models/category_model.dart';
import 'package:kavarna/pages/models/gallery_model.dart';

class MenuModel {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  double? price;
  String? description;
  CategoryModel? categories;
  DateTime? createdAt;
  DateTime? updatedAt;
  List<GalleryModel>? gallery;

  MenuModel({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.price,
    this.description,
    this.categories,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.gallery,
  });

  MenuModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    price = double.parse(json['price'].toString());
    description = json['description'];
    categories = CategoryModel.fromJson(json['categories']);
    gallery = json['gallery'];
    createdAt = DateTime.parse(json['created_at']);
    updatedAt = DateTime.parse(json['updated_at']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'price': price,
      'description': description,
      'category': categories?.toJson(),
      'gallery': gallery,
      'created_at': createdAt,
      'updated_at': updatedAt,
    };
  }
}
```

is there a better way to show data from my menuProvider.menuries ?

Comment: This is expected behaviour, you are printing "[an] instance of [the] MenuModel [class]" so the print statement prints "Instance of MenuModel". you should pass this data into the class like this: `return MenuPage(id: snapshot.data.id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its solved by myself  i just need to change the add List in the middle of my return data like this

```
List data = json.decode(response.body)['data']['data'];
List<MenuModel> menuries = [];
```

Comment: Could you please make it more detailed?